# Creating a document in couchbase from code behind

Tags: c#, nosql, couchbase

I have been using CouchDB. Now i'm trying to migrate my application from CouchDb to CouchBase.

What is the equivalent code for

```
public CouchResponse CreateDocument(string jsonForDocument);
```

in couchbase.?

I hav used the following code for querying the create document in couchdb..

```
CouchDatabase oCouchDB;

oClient = new CouchClient(host, port, username, password, false, AuthenticationType.Cookie, 30000);
oCouchDB = oClient.GetDatabase(baseDatabase);
CouchResponse resp = oCouchDB.CreateDocument(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRUD functions in Couchbase are performed via the memcached API (key/value).

Please see http://www.couchbase.com/develop/net/next for more information.